# Apple Sign In - Hide by Email option - Issue with Tokenised email address

Tags: ios, swift, sign-in-with-apple

We are developing a mobile app that allows users to purchase gift cards from popular retailers, and this app requires valid email address during login/register which is needed for mapping all user’s wallet and gift card details.

This app also supports social login like Apple, Facebook and Google and we are also providing a web platform where users can check their gift cards and wallet informations.

We are currently facing an issue with Apple SignIn when using “Hide by Email” flow. We observed that in this flow, the app generates a tokenised email address for user to login, and the same tokenised email address will be mapped to the user's gift card and wallet information.

Assume that an user register with mobile app using tokenised email address and the same user login into the web platform with a valid email address. In this flow, the user will not be able to see the wallet and  purchased gift card information which could result in data issues and discrepancies between web and mobile apps.

We would like to know for any option to disable or remove “Hide by Email” from Apple’s SignIn popup. If not, could you suggest us a way to fix this issue.

We investigated that whether it was possible to disable or eliminate "Hide by Email" from Apple's Sign-In window, but we were unable to identify the right fix.

Comment: The email address supplied is the email address the user wants to use. The same "hide my email" address is available to the user on their Mac; your web site should also support Sign in with Apple. . If they sign in with a different email address then they will not see their gift card details because they have signed in with a different account. How does hide my email change anything? A hide my email address is a "valid email address".